# Unable to config and run a Java project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Me and a few other students are building a game with Java at university. Someone else setup the basic structure for the project and i pulled the repo and tried to run it.

When i run it i get
[this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSw7Y.png)

When i open the config, i am unable to add the main class, it is located in the file shown in the image. The OK button is disabled. You can see that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWA9b.png).

I'm running the latest version of IntelliJ, JDK 9 and Windows 10. The project in question is built with [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). The full repo and folder structure can be seen [here](https://github.com/johannesmols/GangsterSquirrel).

I am able to setup my own project and run my own apps, i just can't run this specific project.

Please help.

Comment: Have you imported the project as Gradle project?

Comment: Yes, and it was built without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think, since you have no "Java" directory, Intellij does not recognize any folder as Java Sources. You'll have to do that manually by rightclicking and mark the desired directory as Source root.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, and of course - it was obvious. The project was setup with an old version of Gradle (2.4) and i was running Java 9. I installed Java 8 and made the project run.

The OK button was disabled because the project hadn't built properly (i though it had) so it couldn't find the class i needed to run it.